# Does the default destructor remove a dynamically created object?

Tags: c++, dynamic

I have written the `demo` class. It allocated the array `arr` dynamically. Do I need to write the default destructor `~demo` as shown in the code to free up the memory allocated to `arr` or the default destructor does that itself?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class demo
{

    int *arr;

public:
    demo(int n)
    {
        arr = new int[n];
    }
    ~demo()
    {
        delete[] arr;
    }
};
int main()
{
    demo obj(10);
    cout << "done\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you use `std::vector` here, instead of calling `new`, you can forget about memory management entirely.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: Thanks! Can you elaborate that, please? I'm new to this. And how to I learn about this?

Comment: `~demo()` is a *destructor*, not a constructor.  The `demo(int n)` is a constructor.   But, in short, if your code does an explicit `new` expression somewhere, it is necessary to ensure a corresponding `delete` expression is performed exactly once for every time the `new` expression is executed.   So, yes, your destructor is necessary.   You might also wish to investigate "rule of three" or (C++11 and later) "rule of five", to avoid other cases in which a `new` expression in your class is unmatched by a corresponding `delete` expression.

Comment: Also, in your class definition, you only have one constructor that takes an argument `n`. The default constructor in C++ is a constructor that can be called with no arguments. So your class does not currently have a default constructor.

Comment: If you want that behavior use std::vector<int>, in current C++ try to avoid the use of new/delete unless you are really implementing a datastructure of your own.